# I am sending UDP packets from localhost to localhost and runs on packets sometimes drop. How do I stop this and why does it happen?

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, udp

This is output from my program

```
sending agent update
Created new player
Identified
sending agent update
Physics: 2 ticks this frame
time= 200
time= 300
***Packet Dropped: 2:10 ***
***Packet Dropped: 2:11 ***
***Packet Dropped: 2:12 ***
***Packet Dropped: 2:13 ***
***Packet Dropped: 2:14 ***
***Packet Dropped: 2:15 ***
***Packet Dropped: 2:16 ***
***Packet Dropped: 2:17 ***
***Packet Dropped: 2:18 ***
***Packet Dropped: 2:19 ***
***Packet Dropped: 2:20 ***
***Packet Dropped: 2:21 ***
time= 400
Physics: 2 ticks this frame
time= 500
Physics: 2 ticks this frame
```

Sending packets from local host to local host, packets are dropping.  This only happens near the beginning.  The first 10 or so packets get through, then packets after that drop.  5 to 40 packets in a row.  Then packets stop dropping.

Is there any reason that this should happen?

**Update:**

The following code fixed the problem.

```
int buffsize = 65536; // 65536
setsockopt(socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, (void*)&buffsize, sizeof(buffsize));
```

I was sending packets too fast and exceeded the windows default receive buffer, which is only 8 KB.  Increasing the buffer size fixed the problem.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the code. Too many unknowns.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check the UDP buffer size configured by default in your OS.

If you find it less, you can explicitly provide a greater value while creating a UDP socket.

```
int buffer_size = 4 * 1024 * 1024 ;
setsockopt(socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, &buffer_size, sizeof(buffer_size));
```

You may find [THIS](http://wwwx.cs.unc.edu/~sparkst/howto/network_tuning.php)  link pretty useful.

Comment: I came up with this solution before reading your answer, but you are absolutely correct.  This solved my problem.

Comment: I recently had a similar problem and I ran into a hard limit for the maximum receive/send buffer sizes. Increasing those to some high value solved the problem: `sysctl -w net.core.rmem_max=$[2*1024*1024]` and `sysctl -w net.core.wmem_max=$[2*1024*1024]`. Funny enough `setsockopt` did *not* return an error and seems to just ignore values larger than this maximum.

Comment: @hochl I agree, it can be bit frustrating (having faced it myself one time :) )

Answer (score 4):

You're probably sending packets too quickly and thus overflowing buffers. You need to implement transmit pacing to make sure the transmitter does not overwhelm the receiver. You will never 100% avoid this -- it's the nature of UDP that it does not provide a delivery guarantee.

Answer (score 1):

As a really quick guess - in the past I've seen this because receive windows are full. Basically your application is not consuming the packets fast enough and the kernel only has so much space reserved - you need to increase the rwin parameter. Or on the other side you are sending them too fast - the params on a Linux box are

```
net.ipv4.udp_rmem_min = 4096
net.ipv4.udp_wmem_min = 4096
```